# Changing a variable value balance

Tags: expr

I am practicing unix, self learning so I done some basic coding of creating a cash machine. so far I have done the following and need some guidance on the final hurdle

I am stuck on how I can update the value. e.g if the user selects option:-
1=5
2=10
3=20
4=50

I was thinking it would be as easy as something like this `expr $bal1 +5`

or should I be using the awk and sed command to pull the current value then + the value the user enters?

Here is the code, its actually all in one file

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is an automated cash machine

##########################
#Created Variables
##########################
user1=1234
user2=0000
user3=0124
name1=Mike
name1=John
name2=Brad
name3=Sophie
bal1=0
bal2=0
bal3=0
###################################
#Created functions add_funds
###################################

main_screen ()
{
    echo "####################################"
    echo "1.\tAdd Funds"
    echo "2.\tWithdraw Funds"
    echo "3.\tCheck Balance"
    echo "4.\tExit"
    echo "####################################"

    echo "Enter Option:\c"
    read number

    if [ $number = 1 ]
    then
        add_funds

    elif [ $number = 2 ]
    then
        clear
        echo "withdraw Funds"

    elif [ $number = 3 ]
    then
        clear 
        echo "Show balance"

    elif [ $number = 4 ]
    then
        exit

    else   
        echo "wrong selection, try again"
        sleep 1
        clear 
        while [ $number -gt 4 ]; do
            main_screen
        done
    fi
}

add_funds ()
{
    clear
    echo "How much would you like to add?"
    echo "select one of the following options"

    echo "1.\t£5.00"
    echo "2.\t£10.00"
    echo "3.\t£20.00"
    echo "4.\t£50.00"

    echo "Enter Option:\c"

    read amount

    if [ $amount = 1 ]
    then
        $((`expr $bal1+5`)) #this does not work
        echo "you have added £5.00"
        echo "ACCOUNT UPDATED $bal1"

    elif [ $amount = 2 ]
    then
        echo "you have added £10.00"
        echo "ACCOUNT UPDATED"
    elif [ $amount = 3 ]
    then
        echo "you have added £20.00"
        echo "ACCOUNT UPDATED"
    elif [ $amount = 4 ]
    then
        echo "you have added £50.00"
        echo "ACCOUNT UPDATED"
    else
        echo "wrong selection, try again"
        sleep 1
        while [ $amount -gt 4 ]; do
            add_funds
        done
    fi
}

################################
# MAIN CODE
################################

clear
echo "***********************"
echo "   CASH DESPENSER      "
echo "***********************"

echo "Enter Pin:\c"

read pin

if [ $pin = $user1 ]
then
    clear
    echo "Welcome $name1, How can I assist you"
    main_screen
elif [ $pin = $user2 ]
then
    clear
    echo "Welcome $name2, How can I assist you"
    main_screen
elif [ $pin = $user3 ]
then
    clear
    echo "Welcome $name3, how can I assist you"
    main_screen
else
    echo "Incorrect pin user, try again"
fi
```

Comment: Try: `bal=$((bal + 5))`

Comment: II changed the code

Comment: and now using bal1=$((ballers + 5 )) - this seems to add the value. but when I check at the above code for bal1 it remains as 0.

Comment: TYPO Earlier.        bal1=$((bal + 5))

Comment: I am just thinking do I need to use a sed -I command in place for this as well ?>

Comment: I suggest you boil this down to a simple question that focuses on what you're having trouble with.

Comment: its basically to update the value bal1, the value should always increment. So if bal1=0 and the user enters to add 5 then the total = bal1=5, next time running if the user again adds 5 then bal1=10.

Comment: however the value is not storing to bal1

Comment: ##########################
#Created Variables
##########################
user1=1234
user2=0000
user3=0124
name1=Mike
name1=John
name2=Brad
name3=Sophie
bal1=0
bal2=0
bal3=0
###################################

Comment: Replace `$((`expr $bal1+5`))` with `(( bal1 += 5 ))`

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comment above, if you want to add 5 to `bal1`, you can do:

```
bal1=$((bal1 + 5))
```

For example:

```
$ x=42
$ echo $x
42
$ x=$((x + 5))
$ echo $x
47
$
```

Comment: Instead of `x-$((x +5))`, you could have used `(( x+=5 ))`

Comment: yep I understand thats, thanks, but when I vi into the editor the value x still remains 42, it should be updated it 47

Comment: the code does work but its just shows on the terminal as a temporary value but does not really update the x value inside the vi editor.

Comment: I started playing around with sed and awk but the sed -I command does not work in my iMac Shell, example below.

Comment: kamruls-iMac:~ hussain$ awk ' { print $1 } ' maths
x=42

((

echo
kamruls-iMac:~ hussain$ grep x= maths | awk ' { print $1 } '
x=42
kamruls-iMac:~ hussain$ grep x= maths | awk ' { print $1 } ' | cut -b 3-4
42
kamruls-iMac:~ hussain$ grep x= maths | awk ' { print $1 } ' | cut -b 3-4 | sed 's/42/50/g'
50
kamruls-iMac:~ hussain$ grep x= maths | awk ' { print $1 } ' | cut -b 3-4 | sed -i 's/42/50/g'
sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're asking.  Do you expect executing the script and modifying the value of a variable in memory to change the text of the script itself?